# Undefined reference to `round' c language

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm using those imports

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

and I'm getting *undefined reference to `round'* at this line:

```
double res = round(atof(nextVal));
```

*nextVal* is a double value read from a file.

I'm using Eclipse INDIGO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In command line, you must specify `-lm` option to gcc to link the math lib. You have to find how to do so in eclipse.